# Concatenate consecutive (related) objects in array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, grouping, object-literal

Given the following array:

```
const activities = [
  { type: 'car', duration: 60 },
  { type: 'car', duration: 140 },
  { type: 'ferry', duration: 60 },
  { type: 'car', duration: 100 }
];
```

What would be the best approach to merge 
consecutive objects with `type: 'car'` while retaining the order of elements? In this example, the desired result would be:

```
const activities = [
  { type: 'car', duration: 200 }, // merged
  { type: 'ferry', duration: 60 },
  { type: 'car', duration: 100 } // this stays
];
```

The array is built dynamically and the example is simplified for clarity.

After quite some attemps I've managed to write working code, using a combination of `do/while`, `findIndex()`, `slice()` and `reduce()` to populate a new array. The code feels cumbersome and involves many operations, though.

I'm left wondering if there is an easy approach (that I'm not seeing) to solve this problem... any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: please add the code ...

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the abovementioned question. It's more complex as only 
consecutive objects should be merged...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate the objects. If the last item in the accumulator has the same type as that of the current item (`o`), add the duration to the last item. If not add the current object to the accumulator.

```js
const activities = [
  { type: 'car', duration: 60 },
  { type: 'car', duration: 140 },
  { type: 'ferry', duration: 60 },
  { type: 'car', duration: 100 }
];

const result = activities.reduce((r, o) => {
  const last = r[r.length - 1];
  
  if(last && last.type === o.type) last.duration += o.duration;
  else r.push({ ...o });
  
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure one of the masters will refine this further. But using a set to collate is the trick here.
NOTE: if you want to sum the values, just remove my array init and push and go with a +=

```js
const activities = [
  { type: 'car', duration: 60 },
  { type: 'car', duration: 140 },
  { type: 'ferry', duration: 60 },
  { type: 'car', duration: 100 }
];


var newSet = new Set();

activities.forEach(activity => {
  if(newSet.has(activity.type) == false) {
    newSet.add(activity.type);
    newSet[activity.type] = [];
  }
  newSet[activity.type].push(activity.duration);
});

console.log(newSet);
```